# Why does loop never exit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a Bisectional Number guessing game and I would like to make it work automatically, but the code appears to be getting stuck in a loop.

Any suggestions?

```
x = 75

low = 0
high = 100

guessing = True

while guessing:

    guess = int((high + low) // 2)

    if guess == x:
        guessing = False
    elif guess < x:
        high = guess
    else:
        low = guess

print("Your number is ", str(guess))
```

Comment: You should run through your algorithm "by hand" and see what it does. As Kalpesh says, you've got your `elif...else` logic reversed.

Comment: I feel dumb now. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work:

```
x = 75
low = 0
high = 100
guessing = True
while guessing:
    guess = (high + low) // 2
    print("guess:",guess)
    if guess == x:
        guessing = False
    elif guess < x:
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
print("Your number is ", guess)
```

output:

```
guess: 50
guess: 75
Your number is  75
```

You don't need to explicitly convert it to int because you are using integer division here  `guess = int((high + low) // 2)` And reverse the `elif ..else` logic..

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For such things it's better to limit the number of possible iterations.

```
max_iter = 25
x = 42
low , high = 0 , 100

for _ in range(max_iter):
    guess = (high + low) // 2
    if guess == x:
        break
    low , high = (guess , high) if x > guess else (low , guess)

print("Your number is {}".format(guess))
```